# Allocating 8MB physically contiguous memory in Linux

Tags: linux, arch-linux, linux-kernel, drivers, c

Can I allocate more than 4MB physically contiguous memory without enabling `CONFIG_CMA` kernel config parameter? Currently, I am using `dma_alloc_coherent()` call, but it fails if I try to allocate a memory more than 4MB size.

Answer (score 1):

See [`__get_free_pages()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.1.9/source/mm/page_alloc.c#L5604).

From a description from the [O'Reilly Linux device drivers book](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/linux-device-drivers/0596005903/ch08.html), a dated but still relevant book:

> If a module needs to allocate big chunks of memory, it is usually better to use a page-oriented technique. ...
>
> The `flags` argument works in the same way as with *kmalloc*; usually either `GFP_KERNEL` or `GFP_ATOMIC` is used, perhaps with the addition of the `__GFP_DMA` flag (for memory that can be used for ISA direct-memory-access operations) or `__GFP_HIGHMEM` when high memory can be used.  `order` is the base-two logarithm of the number of pages you are requesting or freeing (i.e., log2 N). For example, `order` is 0 if you want one page and 3 if you request eight pages. If `order` is too big (no contiguous area of that size is available), the page allocation fails. The *get_order* function, which takes an integer argument, can be used to extract the order from a size (that must be a power of two) for the hosting platform. The maximum allowed value for order is 10 or 11 (corresponding to 1024 or 2048 pages), depending on the architecture. The chances of an order-10 allocation succeeding on anything other than a freshly booted system with a lot of memory are small, however.